# PyMongo: NatType ValueError on Bulk Insert to New Collection

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to use PyMongo to upload a mixed set of date and text data to a new collection in my remote MongoDB server.

However, I'm getting a error as a result of null values mixed in with dates—i.e. rows where there is a `None` value instead of a `datetime.datetime()` object.

As some background: The raw data is stored in a CSV file, which I'm reading into a `pandas.DataFrame()` using `pandas.read_csv()`. Once I have the data in `pandas`, I do some rudimentary cleaning before transforming the data into a list of dictionaries, which I then upload to the collection using the standard `collection.insert_many()` method.

Initially, the values in each row / document / dictionary are stored as strings. However, before uploading the data, I convert a number of date columns into `datetime` objects by calling `datetime.datetime.strptime()` on each value. Not every dictionary has these date fields populated, though. For these dictionaries, I simply use a `None` instead of a `datetime` object.

The resulting data that I'm trying to upload, then, is a **list of dictionaries with a number of NoneType values mixed in,** and when I call `insert_many()` I get this:

`ValueError: NaTType does not support utcoffset.`

I'm not familiar with `utcoffset`, and my attempts to research this have confounded me.

Has anyone run into this issue, or have suggestions on how to **handle missing datetime data** in PyMongo?

Here's my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import pymongo

source = '/path/to/data'
sampleData = pd.read_csv(source, dtype=str)

Date_Columns = [
    'date_a',
    'date_b',
    'date_c',
    'date_d'
]
cleanData = sampleData
for col in Date_Columns:

    # Convert the strings to datetime objects for each column.
    # If a value is null, then use a None object instead of a datetime.
    Strings = sampleData[col].values
    Formats = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, '%m/%d/%Y') if isinstance(d, str) else None for d in Strings]
    cleanData[col] = Formats

client = pymongo.MongoClient('XX.XX.XX.XX', 99999)
db = client['my_db']
c = db['my_collection']

# Convert the cleaned DataFrame into a list of dictionaries.
Keys = [key for key in sampleData.columns.values]
Data = [dict(zip(Keys, L)) for L in sampleData.values]

c.insert_many(Data)
```

And full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/haru/my_git/projects/pipeline/stable/sofla_permits_sunnyisles.py", line 738, in <module>
    setup_db()
  File "/Users/haru/my_git/projects/pipeline/stable/sofla_permits_sunnyisles.py", line 679, in setup_db
    c.insert_many(Data)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 753, in insert_many
    blk.execute(write_concern, session=session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 513, in execute
    return self.execute_command(generator, write_concern, session)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 338, in execute_command
    self.is_retryable, retryable_bulk, s, self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 1196, in _retry_with_session
    return func(session, sock_info, retryable)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 333, in retryable_bulk
    retryable, full_result)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/bulk.py", line 285, in _execute_command
    self.collection.codec_options, bwc)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/message.py", line 1273, in _do_bulk_write_command
    namespace, operation, command, docs, check_keys, opts, ctx)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pymongo/message.py", line 1263, in _do_batched_write_command
    namespace, operation, command, docs, check_keys, opts, ctx)
  File "pandas/_libs/tslibs/nattype.pyx", line 59, in pandas._libs.tslibs.nattype._make_error_func.f
ValueError: NaTType does not support utcoffset
```

Comment: I think it was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42228292/pymongo-valueerror-nattype-does-not-support-utcoffset-when-using-insert-many

Answer (score 3):

Most machines have their clocks set to `utc`, which is ideal. It's an integer value of seconds from a given date (sometime in the 70's, I believe). What this means is that your schedules for processes don't rely on local time, including the massive headache that is Daylight Savings.

UTC offset from US Eastern Standard is 4-5 hours (depending on daylight savings).

Looking at your error, this is a `pandas` error, and `pandas.datetime` does *not* play nicely with `datetime.datetime`. Convert it to a datetime `string` of the required precision. That should avoid this error.